# How to describe strength of keeping things simple and beautiful

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm writing performance review of one of my colleagues that includes describing his strengths.

For example, one of his strengths is *Communication*. He can quickly resolve conflicts with co-workers, and effectively explain policy changes to vendors.

One thing that I'd like to mention is, he has some kind of aesthetic feeling, he enjoys keeping things simple and beautiful, and had designed relatively exquisite and user friendly interface.

Which word should I use to describe this strength?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could say he has a flair for *[elegance](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/elegance)*:

> a. Refinement, grace, and beauty in movement, appearance, or manners.
>   b. Tasteful opulence in form, decoration, or presentation

Comment: I like _elegant_ as well, but I'd explicitly mention a penchant for elegant _design_. In its entry for _elegant_, NOAD defines the word as _pleasingly graceful and stylish in appearance or manner_, with the example _"she will look elegant in black."_ Yet there's also a subdefinition which reads: _(of a scientific theory or solution to a problem) pleasingly ingenious and simple_; I think **that's** the meaning of the word the O.P. wants. (Without mentioning _design_ or _solutions_, one might read the performance review, and wonder, "Why would I care how elegant this person dresses for work?")

Comment: What J.R. said. I'm more likely to read/talk about scientific theories and software algorithms than *haute couture*, so for me personally, *pleasingly ingenious and simple* is usually the first definition that comes to mind with no other context.

Answer (score 2):

“Straightforward”, “balanced” and “clear” are positive terms to call someone’s work skills that exhibit this aesthetic – also “effective” is a very positive term.  (Very “bottom-line” that one.)  “Impeccable” is even more forceful.  *“His design work is impeccable”*  is, to my mind, about as good as it gets.

Some cross-reference of words you yourself used:

http://thesaurus.com/browse/simple

http://thesaurus.com/browse/beautiful

http://thesaurus.com/browse/exquisite

http://thesaurus.com/browse/user+friendly

Comment: Usage Note: an accountant or secretary, who requires exactitude, is more apt to be “impeccable”.  An artist, say the designer of a web page, would be more creative.  In that sense I really like @Sudhir’s idea of immaculate, but – like impeccable – can be an overstatement.  - “Functional and inspired”, “Powerful and effective”,  “Uncluttered and creative”,  “Beautiful and inspireING”,  “Sleek and gorgeous”, “Subtle and uncanny work”.  Etc.  (This is easy!  I’m imagining someone talking about MY work! :)  [But, frankly, I’m describing Japanese art, or the beloved Google homepage.]

Answer (score 0):

Well, ipso's answer is sufficient to your question. But still I would like to add some more words:
*immaculate*:

> She speaks immaculate French.

In this context *perfect* may also mean the same.
 All these words are used to show that somebody is free of flaws and is exceptionally good in his/her skills. Also these words reflects a high degree of competency in their skills.